# Transform table following ID using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

| Purchase_ID | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 21/3/2020 |
| 1 | B | 21/3/2020 |
| 1 | C | 21/3/2020 |
| 2 | X | 27/3/2020 |
| 2 | Y | 27/3/2020 |

I would like to transform the table into the output below using pandas/any python modules

| Purchase_ID | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,C | 21/3/2020 |
| 2 | X,Y | 27/3/2020 |

Comment: Updated answer below so eliminated sets and provides the strings you want.

Comment: @Daniel so you didn't want efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Purchase_ID', values=['Item','Date'], aggfunc=set)
```

Note: you'll get a set, rather than list, for the Items and Dates. This avoids duplicating the dates.

If you want to get rid of the sets, you can convert to strings:

```
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])
df2['Item'] = df2['Item'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(list(x))
```

Then df2 is the DataFrame you're looking for.

```
out:
               Date       Item
Purchase_ID                      
1            21/3/2020    A,B,C
2            27/3/2020    X,Y
```

Answer (score 1):

try via `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
out=df.groupby('Purchase_ID',as_index=False).agg({'Item':','.join,'Date':'first'})
```

If needed unique elements then use:

```
out=df.groupby('Purchase_ID',as_index=False).agg({'Item':lambda x:','.join(set(x)),'Date':'first'})
```

output of `out`:

```
    Purchase_ID     Item    Date
0   1               A,C,B   21/3/2020
1   2               Y,X     27/3/2020
```

Comment: @anarug I like that your answer is one line, and I expect higher performance than mine since it avoids two separate apply calls so upvoted, but I don't understand the syntax. Specifically, how does the `agg({col name:func, col2 name:func})` work? You're passing a set into the agg function, but also a dict within that set to apply different functions to each element of the set? And could it be a list? And since when is first an agg func? Is that built in? In short, what's going on in that magical, magical agg call?

Comment: @BLimitless Sir basically `agg({col name:func, col2 name:func})` syntax means *Different aggregations per column* here in the example `{'Item':lambda x:','.join(set(x)),'Date':'first'}` it is performing `set()` on 'Item' of grouped *Purchase_ID* via anonymous function and then joining them with `,` and on 'Date' it is choosing the first value based on grouping on *Purchase_ID* in simple words it is choosing the first date per unique *Purchase id*......passing dict in agg() method is syntax to passing key value pairs for aggregration and yes it is 3 times faster then pivot_table and then using

Comment: apply()  even Sir you can check the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html ...In documentation they have given an example